# How to add two select queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Can the below sql query be possible.
I want to have three counts from the same table in different columns with one query only.

```
select COUNT(Status) as attendedcount from Ebrahim_30359715 where Status='Attended' 
UNION 
select COUNT(Status) as notallocatedcount from Ebrahim_30359715  where Status='Not Allocated'
UNION 
select COUNT(Status) as allocatedbutnotcount from Ebrahim_30359715  where Status='Allocated But Not Attended'
```

Answer (score 2):

Better use

```
select SUM(case when Status='Attended' then 1 end) as attendedcount,
       SUM(case when Status='Not Attended' then 1 end) as notallocatedcount,
       SUM(case when Status='Allocated But Not Attended' then 1 end) as allocatedbutnotcount
from Ebrahim_30359715
```

With `union` you would have to either make 3 different columns or add an extra column indicating which value you store in column1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. This will work for new status too. you don't have to explicitly mention the status

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(max), 
        @sql  AS NVARCHAR(max) 

SELECT @cols = Stuff((SELECT ',' + Quotename(status) 
                      FROM   Ebrahim_30359715
                      GROUP  BY status 
                      FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1,'') 

SET @sql = 'select *  from  
                      (select count(1) as cnt ,status
                       from Ebrahim_30359715
                       group by status )
            src pivot (max(cnt) for status in (' + @cols + ')) piv' 

EXEC Sp_executesql 
     @sql
```

Comment: Had to try this for myself & I like it.